# Block installing from apk file

Tags: android, block, apk

Is it possible to block installing apps from apk file directly. How can do this using code, not by using some setting on the phone.

I just need to block installation of apps outside of the play store. That is stop the user from copying a apk file to the phone and install it. But still allow them to install apps through the Play Store.

Comment: All apps are installed from apk files....

Comment: @Raghav Sood i have explained my requirement better.Is it possible to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible on AOSP Android.

The Install from unknown sources option is a setting in `Settings.Global` (previously in `Settings.Secure`) and cannot be controlled by third party applications.

However, it is possible do achieve this if you're willing to modify and compile Android itself for each and every device you want to use this on, as is done by AT&T on some of their devices.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.** This is a system setting you can't handle, because it's a security setting. This won't be editable by any application. Just think about what if, when any application could do: Then the application could download a bad .apk and install it without any warning.

Answer (score 0):

try using code to copy file into directry /data/app/ .
but device is rooted and some app work not correctly